# Node js : Mongoose and mongo connecting problem

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

While I try to connect mongodb with express js with mongoose and I am getting error for a long. How to fix this is ?

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello from node js')
})

const connection_url = 'connection-url';

mongoose.connect(connection_url, {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(()=> console.log("Database Connected"));

app.listen(3000);
```

**This is the error**

```
node:14460) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\MyFolder\Coding\DB connection\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:846:32)
    at C:\MyFolder\Coding\DB connection\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:351:10
    at C:\MyFolder\Coding\DB connection\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\MyFolder\Coding\DB connection\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\MyFolder\Coding\DB connection\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1149:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\MyFolder\Coding\DB connection\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:350:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\MyFolder\Coding\DB connection\index.js:11:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:14460) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14460) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How to fix this is and connect to the mongodb ??

Comment: Did you read what it suggests in the error? Also you need to change your credentials now.

Comment: You'd better not share the connection_url private to you.

Comment: There is no error in your code. Error on Atlas.

Comment: Suggestion: Don't share connection string publicly. Your error clearly shows that you have to whitelist your IP.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to MongoDB Atlas
2. Open your cluster
3. Go to settings > Network Access

[image]

4. Add IP Addresss

[image]

5. Click on Allow access on anywhere `||` Just add your current IP
6. Restart your app and it should be working

Comment: No Its not working , I tried it for a few times. I have a doubt is there any problem if i am using internet data through a hotspot of my phone